# Error in try/except construction

Tags: python

Im just sitting for 10 minutes staring at a simple piece of code, which I have copied from a guide and I can't understand why I am getting an error.

```
def transformation(x):
    date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"
    try:
        a = dt.date(int(x[6:10]), int(x[3:5]), int(x[0:2]))
    else:
        a = dt.datetime.strptime(x, date_format)
    finally: 
        return a
  File "<ipython-input-91-f1f6fe70d542>", line 5
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Maybe this is just me... Whats wrong?
**After adding `except`**:

```
def transformation(x):
    date_format = "%d/%m/%Y"
    try:
        a = dt.date(int(x[6:10]), int(x[3:5]), int(x[0:2]))
    except pass 
    else:
        a = dt.datetime.strptime(x, date_format)
    finally: 
        return a
File "<ipython-input-93-c2285c857574>", line 5
    except pass 
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need an `except` clause to use `else`:

> The `try ... except` statement has an optional `else` clause, which, when
>   present, must **follow** all `except` clauses
>   [*Emphasis mine*]

Comment: please,see edit

Comment: You need a colon after `except`.

Answer (score 0):

I just saw it from the python document page, so I'm just gonna quote what it says to you:

> The try ... except statement has an optional else clause, which, when present, must follow all except clauses. It is useful for code that must be executed if the try clause does not raise an exception. For example:
>
> ```
>  for arg in sys.argv[1:]:
>         try:
>             f = open(arg, 'r')
>         except IOError:
>             print('cannot open', arg)
>         else:
>             print(arg, 'has', len(f.readlines()), 'lines')
>             f.close()
> ```